# Detecting whether image contains object or not

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, object-detection

I've been able to train a CNN for binary classification. It detects whether an image is more likely to contain object A or object B (it returns 0 or 1).

How would I go about building a network that detects whether object A is in an image or not (and nothing else)? Do I need to give it training data that doesn't contain A?

I only need to know if an object is contained in the image, not where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Collect a lot of images that are "similar" to whatever you will apply your trained model to (so you don't fall prey to [concept drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_drift)), some of which contain A and some don't. The target variable would be TRUE or FALSE, depending on whether A is in there or not. Then start training.